# Why does docker compose intermittently lose communication between containers?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I've been using this `docker compose` configuration for a couple of years in production now, and it's been fine until randomly crashing twice in the past week...

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: backend
    build: ..
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 8000
    ports:
      - 9109:8000
    env_file:
      - &ENV_FILE ../.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - worker
    volumes:
      - &MEDIA_VOLUME /srv/media/:/srv/media
      - &STATIC_VOLUME /srv/static/:/srv/static
      - &TMP_VOLUME /tmp/:/tmp/host/
    logging:
      driver: journald
      options:
        tag: docker-web
  worker:
    image: backend
    environment:
      - REMAP_SIGTERM=SIGQUIT
    command: /usr/bin/start-worker.sh
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - *ENV_FILE
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - *MEDIA_VOLUME
      - *STATIC_VOLUME
      - *TMP_VOLUME
    logging:
      driver: journald
      options:
        tag: docker-worker
  db:
    image: mdillon/postgis:11
    shm_size: '256m'
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - *ENV_FILE
    volumes:
      - /var/docker-postgres/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - *TMP_VOLUME
    logging:
      driver: journald
      options:
        tag: docker-db
  memcached:
    container_name: memcached
    image: memcached:latest
    ports:
        - "11211:11211"
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
```

Suddenly last week I started seeing errors from the `web` process:

- `could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known`
- `Error -2 connecting to redis:6379. Name or service not known.`

When I checked on the processes they all seemed to be running:

```
$ docker-compose ps
      Name                     Command               State                Ports              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
docker_db_1         docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      5432/tcp                        
docker_rabbitmq_1   docker-entrypoint.sh rabbi ...   Up      15671/tcp, 0.0.0.0:15672->15672/
                                                             tcp,:::15672->15672/tcp,        
                                                             15691/tcp, 15692/tcp, 25672/tcp,
                                                             4369/tcp, 5671/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5672
                                                             ->5672/tcp,:::5672->5672/tcp    
docker_redis_1      docker-entrypoint.sh redis ...   Up      6379/tcp                        
docker_web_1        /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/start.sh     Up      0.0.0.0:9109->8000/tcp,:::9109->
                                                             8000/tcp                        
docker_worker_1     /usr/bin/start-worker.sh         Up                                      
memcached           docker-entrypoint.sh memcached   Up      0.0.0.0:11211->11211/tcp,:::1121
                                                             1->11211/tcp
```

However it seems the containers were unable to communicate as these errors continued indefinitely until I `stop`ped the containers and `start`ed them again. Then everything was fine, for a few days, until it suddenly happened again without probable cause...

Any ideas what might be happening?!

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 24.0.1, build 6802122
$ uname -a
Linux redacted 3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 14 13:59:45 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` in `web` container:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

### UPDATE

OK found some clues in `/var/log/messages` at the time of the latest crash (this morning):

```
# still working at this point
May 27 05:02:07 my-hostname yum[31556]: Updated: docker-buildx-plugin.x86_64 0.10.5-1.el7
May 27 05:02:09 my-hostname yum[31556]: Updated: docker-ce-cli.x86_64 1:24.0.2-1.el7
May 27 05:02:10 my-hostname yum[31556]: Updated: docker-ce-rootless-extras.x86_64 24.0.2-1.el7
May 27 05:02:16 my-hostname yum[31556]: Updated: docker-ce.x86_64 3:24.0.2-1.el7
May 27 05:02:16 my-hostname systemd: Reloading.
May 27 05:02:17 my-hostname systemd: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
May 27 05:02:17 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:17.087647049+10:00" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
May 27 05:02:17 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:17.113911997+10:00" level=info msg="Daemon shutdown complete"
May 27 05:02:17 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:17.117216292+10:00" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
May 27 05:02:17 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:17.117728466+10:00" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
May 27 05:02:17 my-hostname systemd: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
May 27 05:02:17 my-hostname systemd: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
May 27 05:02:17 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:17.301708572+10:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
May 27 05:02:18 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:18.895994520+10:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
May 27 05:02:30 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:30.709737036+10:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
May 27 05:02:30 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:30.754470385+10:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
May 27 05:02:30 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:30.756943164+10:00" level=error msg="stream copy error: reading from a closed fifo"
May 27 05:02:30 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:30.798420878+10:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=562f53739a6c564fb7ca240a68de87489c5132f513977ae53012ecba752d90c4 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
May 27 05:02:30 my-hostname containerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:30.798418353+10:00" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=562f53739a6c564fb7ca240a68de87489c5132f513977ae53012ecba752d90c4
May 27 05:02:30 my-hostname containerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:30.798866207+10:00" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=562f53739a6c564fb7ca240a68de87489c5132f513977ae53012ecba752d90c4 namespace=moby
May 27 05:02:30 my-hostname containerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:30.798950034+10:00" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim"
May 27 05:02:30 my-hostname containerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:30.827844408+10:00" level=warning msg="cleanup warnings time=\"2023-05-27T05:02:30+10:00\" level=info msg=\"starting signal loop\" namespace=moby pid=22533 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2\n"
May 27 05:02:30 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:30.924708741+10:00" level=info msg="Firewalld: docker zone already exists, returning"
May 27 05:02:31 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
May 27 05:02:31 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D PREROUTING' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
May 27 05:02:31 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D OUTPUT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
May 27 05:02:31 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER' failed: iptables: Too many links.
May 27 05:02:31 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1' failed: iptables: Too many links.
May 27 05:02:31 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
May 27 05:02:31 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
May 27 05:02:31 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i br-7630a2794dac -o br-7630a2794dac -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
May 27 05:02:31 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:31.454941777+10:00" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-7630a2794dac already part of docker zone, returning"
May 27 05:02:31 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:31.522751685+10:00" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-7630a2794dac already part of docker zone, returning"
May 27 05:02:31 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
May 27 05:02:31 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:31.780958499+10:00" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface docker0 already part of docker zone, returning"
May 27 05:02:31 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:31.844234522+10:00" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface docker0 already part of docker zone, returning"
May 27 05:02:32 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:32.460772601+10:00" level=error msg="failed to populate fields for osl sandbox 9a40c0210cd412288d7c33eb61bad40530ef9ec48f6701bd1e7184c13fa64d3c"
May 27 05:02:32 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:32.485507497+10:00" level=error msg="failed to populate fields for osl sandbox cd0489e190d48bd6f4e1361ffb1ef948c5b62695f1c3cc08c0793a12a36e0a70"
May 27 05:02:32 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:32.511399464+10:00" level=error msg="failed to populate fields for osl sandbox cf16beecf54d69628a896ed823c890010dc59a288545514b3caab4288b96bbd3"
May 27 05:02:32 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:32.538845672+10:00" level=error msg="failed to populate fields for osl sandbox d9d36cdee5fed3740df123decea7d79f189f42de8879500e36c5ce96695603cb"
May 27 05:02:32 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:32.567477583+10:00" level=error msg="failed to populate fields for osl sandbox 6735141218e84ebd4f0dc0bfe178c926eb4aedd878cc957463d44506d2e55e83"
May 27 05:02:32 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:32.597308395+10:00" level=error msg="failed to populate fields for osl sandbox 74703e4f1bd0cc3d22c0eac14e46c3794a8daef00727f775dd4c4389ee728875"
May 27 05:02:32 my-hostname kernel: br-7630a2794dac: port 8(vethdba34b5) entered disabled state
May 27 05:02:32 my-hostname kernel: device vethdba34b5 left promiscuous mode
May 27 05:02:32 my-hostname kernel: br-7630a2794dac: port 8(vethdba34b5) entered disabled state
May 27 05:02:32 my-hostname NetworkManager[708]: <info>  [1685127752.6322] device (vethdba34b5): released from master device br-7630a2794dac
May 27 05:02:33 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:33.030110748+10:00" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 8c4bad304b8e2c68b55d49ae928839050b9e6fc20caf369c6d3fae18f2f22f89 (562f53739a6c564fb7ca240a68de87489c5132f513977ae53012ecba752d90c4)"
May 27 05:02:33 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:33.038984969+10:00" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint 7630a2794dacc176f1eca74b359658aa646fc256cf8189af6a0963e182e8f85f 4f0d21ab87e2c9f5bcca66178add3e2bd787af62be9be0bc1ef21e41d1ddab6e], retrying...."
May 27 05:02:33 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:33.055058812+10:00" level=error msg="failed to populate fields for osl sandbox 945e03bae7b186562c5a3d2993f8d2b4d6fcd1ddea6277743aaac5c20dd26b50"
May 27 05:02:33 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:33.055937650+10:00" level=info msg="there are running containers, updated network configuration will not take affect"
May 27 05:02:33 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:33.058198587+10:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
May 27 05:02:33 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:33.163904779+10:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=659604f graphdriver=overlay2 version=24.0.2
May 27 05:02:33 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:33.164168658+10:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
May 27 05:02:33 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-27T05:02:33.213072781+10:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
May 27 05:02:33 my-hostname systemd: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
# now failing
```

and the previous failure:

```
May 21 07:05:59 my-hostname yum[7323]: Updated: docker-compose-plugin.x86_64 2.18.1-1.el7
May 21 07:06:00 my-hostname yum[7323]: Updated: docker-ce-cli.x86_64 1:24.0.1-1.el7
May 21 07:06:01 my-hostname yum[7323]: Updated: docker-ce-rootless-extras.x86_64 24.0.1-1.el7
# working at this point
May 21 07:06:07 my-hostname yum[7323]: Updated: docker-ce.x86_64 3:24.0.1-1.el7
May 21 07:06:07 my-hostname systemd: Reloading.
May 21 07:06:07 my-hostname systemd: Stopping Docker Application Container Engine...
May 21 07:06:07 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:07.434010268+10:00" level=info msg="Processing signal 'terminated'"
May 21 07:06:07 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:07.462825347+10:00" level=info msg="Daemon shutdown complete"
May 21 07:06:07 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:07.463607568+10:00" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
May 21 07:06:07 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:07.463903566+10:00" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
May 21 07:06:07 my-hostname systemd: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
May 21 07:06:07 my-hostname systemd: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
May 21 07:06:07 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:07.712187157+10:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
May 21 07:06:09 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:09.213598321+10:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
May 21 07:06:21 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:21.320119275+10:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
May 21 07:06:21 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:21.428525472+10:00" level=info msg="Firewalld: docker zone already exists, returning"
May 21 07:06:21 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
May 21 07:06:21 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D PREROUTING' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
May 21 07:06:21 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D OUTPUT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
May 21 07:06:21 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER' failed: iptables: Too many links.
May 21 07:06:21 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1' failed: iptables: Too many links.
May 21 07:06:21 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
May 21 07:06:21 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
May 21 07:06:22 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i br-7630a2794dac -o br-7630a2794dac -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
May 21 07:06:22 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:22.104048740+10:00" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-7630a2794dac already part of docker zone, returning"
May 21 07:06:22 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:22.176584026+10:00" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-7630a2794dac already part of docker zone, returning"
May 21 07:06:22 my-hostname firewalld[704]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
May 21 07:06:22 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:22.493966150+10:00" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface docker0 already part of docker zone, returning"
May 21 07:06:22 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:22.587591571+10:00" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface docker0 already part of docker zone, returning"
May 21 07:06:23 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:23.228002494+10:00" level=error msg="failed to populate fields for osl sandbox bc76908fce84399c2679fb6ec97763ec2b3ed11cfc61599ae25df14cc99cab81"
May 21 07:06:23 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:23.253473513+10:00" level=error msg="failed to populate fields for osl sandbox dfd2cc470474dd5a0dd7f067fc6988621c53e14c86f06be738b55cb248985965"
May 21 07:06:23 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:23.277796542+10:00" level=error msg="failed to populate fields for osl sandbox 53adb48ffcd597198cfb549eab5f9b0e34b6b2d565a82a22ea3b7cfe8198e48b"
May 21 07:06:23 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:23.303381498+10:00" level=error msg="failed to populate fields for osl sandbox 6f664d964c34d953bc869dd97cb52345e7271b991423f6defc277d57ab1d8d18"
May 21 07:06:23 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:23.333007410+10:00" level=error msg="failed to populate fields for osl sandbox 8c780783dc3060797e991c1fa896e894b25faf94a94ca255731928d339a3fca1"
May 21 07:06:23 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:23.363884199+10:00" level=error msg="failed to populate fields for osl sandbox 90004d1d46832307ae98d041c56cea879787fca8c8c9d20c62df0978784b707f"
May 21 07:06:23 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:23.364885308+10:00" level=error msg="failed to populate fields for osl sandbox 945e03bae7b186562c5a3d2993f8d2b4d6fcd1ddea6277743aaac5c20dd26b50"
May 21 07:06:23 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:23.366407341+10:00" level=info msg="there are running containers, updated network configuration will not take affect"
May 21 07:06:23 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:23.368298228+10:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
May 21 07:06:23 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:23.480334538+10:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=463850e graphdriver=overlay2 version=24.0.1
May 21 07:06:23 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:23.480582539+10:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
May 21 07:06:23 my-hostname dockerd: time="2023-05-21T07:06:23.537863940+10:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
May 21 07:06:23 my-hostname systemd: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
# now failing
```

So I think the trigger for the issue is the automatic update of `docker` packages by `yum` in CentOS, and the restarting of the Docker Application Container Engine, after which the networking breaks down. `there are running containers, updated network configuration will not take affect` sounds particularly suspicious!

Aside from turning off automated `yum` updates, how can I ensure that the container networking won't break in these situations?

Comment: No I have no idea, but it appears you are using the default bridge network, rather than a user defined bridge network, which is not recommended as per the documentation:  `The default bridge network is considered a legacy detail of Docker and is not recommended for production use. Configuring it is a manual operation, and it has technical shortcomings.`

Comment: @Philippe ok done

Comment: `could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known` is a *Name Resolution* error. Your DNS (or `/etc/hosts` or whatever you are using to translate IPs to names) isn't resolving the name `"db"` to an IP address -- thus the `'could not translate host name "db" ...'` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I found the issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/45646

It was working for years until the auto-upgrade to `docker-ce.x86_64 3:24.0.1-1.el7` so I assume this Docker bug was introduced at that point.

I've added `docker*` to my `exclude` config in `/etc/yum.conf` for now to avoid broken restarts until the `moby` bug is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a specific network ?

Like that:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: backend
    build: ..
    restart: unless-stopped
    expose:
      - 8000
    ports:
      - 9109:8000
    env_file:
      - &ENV_FILE ../.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - worker
    volumes:
      - &MEDIA_VOLUME /srv/media/:/srv/media
      - &STATIC_VOLUME /srv/static/:/srv/static
      - &TMP_VOLUME /tmp/:/tmp/host/
    logging:
      driver: journald
      options:
        tag: docker-web
    networks:
      my_network:

  worker:
    image: backend
    environment:
      - REMAP_SIGTERM=SIGQUIT
    command: /usr/bin/start-worker.sh
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - *ENV_FILE
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - *MEDIA_VOLUME
      - *STATIC_VOLUME
      - *TMP_VOLUME
    logging:
      driver: journald
      options:
        tag: docker-worker
    networks:
      my_network:

  db:
    image: mdillon/postgis:11
    shm_size: '256m'
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - *ENV_FILE
    volumes:
      - /var/docker-postgres/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      - *TMP_VOLUME
    logging:
      driver: journald
      options:
        tag: docker-db
    networks:
      my_network:

  memcached:
    container_name: memcached
    image: memcached:latest
    ports:
      - "11211:11211"
    networks:
      my_network:

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
    networks:
      my_network:

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    networks: 
      my_network:

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: No, I mentioned that in the bounty comment above -- "Using a user-defined bridge network is definitely a good idea, but using the default bridge doesn't necessarily explain the errors we've been seeing as far as I understand, it'd be nice to know whether switching that will definitely prevent such errors in the future or not." -- I'm after an explanation for how these issues could have occurred, and this has been running fine for years with the default network

Comment: It costs nothing to try ;-)

Comment: true, but even if it runs fine for a year, I won't know for sure whether I've fixed the problem or not without actually finding the cause

Answer (score 0):

Since containers are having issues talking to each other, one thing we can test is whether the DNS resolution working fine or not.

Check if DNS resolution is working correctly within the Docker network. You can try running a temporary container and test if DNS resolution works for the service names. For Eg:

> ```
> docker run --rm -it --network=<your_network> alpine nslookup db
> docker run --rm -it --network=<your_network> alpine nslookup redis
> ```

--> If you have any DNS caching mechanisms in place (e.g., DNS caching on the host machine or within the containers), ensure that they are not causing any conflicts or outdated information.

--> As a last resort Restarting Docker: If the issue persists and you cannot find any other causes, you can try restarting the Docker service itself. This may help resolve any potential networking or DNS-related issues.

--> It's also worth mentioning that updating Docker Compose to the latest versions might help resolve any known issues or bugs. The docker-compose version you are using is docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064

There have been so many new versions released after this. please check here for the latest versions
https://github.com/docker/compose/releases

I have been facing issues because of the low version of docker-compose used in my application. once upgraded to the latest one the was fixed. But the issue was not the exact same as you are facing.

I would not suggest any testing in the Prod environment but in parallel, you can update the docker-compose version and test in dev or qa to monitor for issues.

I would also suggest having a network set in the docker-compose file so that containers will be linked through the external network. I am not sure it can resolve this name resolution issue. But this is something you should be implementing in your services.

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks @Krishnadhas ! I've just updated the question with some crucial logging info which points to a Docker package update as the cause, just need to know how to make it robust in these update situations

Comment: i have added my latest comments above. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76347371/21967160 
Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I have written this as an answer, instead of comment, for text formatting reason.

Can you try to put following in /etc/resolv.conf ?

```
search localdomain
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options edns0 trust-ad ndots:0
```

which is I've got when I run your docker-compose.yml.

Also, check /etc/resolv.conf in all your containers.

Comment: Thanks @Philippe, I've just updated the question with some crucial logging info which points to a Docker package update as the cause, do you know if these changes would make the configuration robust in the face of such updates?

Comment: My suggested changes only reverts /etc/resolv.conf to it's initial state, so unlikely can cause problems. There are many `level=error` in the log you posted, they need more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Such issues when upgrading Docker daemon are expected. On upgrade, Docker daemon will shutdown - and existing containers will be restarted by default.

You can [configure Docker Daemon to enable Live Restore](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/#enable-live-restore). Edit or create `etc/docker/daemon.json` (default path for Docker daemon config on Linux) to specify:

```json
{
  "live-restore": true
}
```

Note however it [may not work for major upgrade](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/#live-restore-during-upgrades) (such as `23.x` > `24.x`) so you may want to configure automatic update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Pierre B., it has been running fine for years with automatic Docker daemon updates, and I added `"live-restore": true` to my `/etc/docker/daemon.json` back in March 2021. Only in the last fortnight has this issue arisen. I wonder if a bug was introduced in Docker recently?

Comment: yep, found the docker bug, see answer I've just added